# Why does InfluxDB returns more data points than I requested?

Tags: grafana

I have InfluxDB (1.8) + Telegraf + Grafana setup. Telegraf sends some metrics to InfluxDB every minute and I would like to calculate SLO (so simply speaking: metric's value is either `0` or `1`, I want to sum of all the received values and divide them by the number of data points).

But it seems that I do not understand how Influx handles queries/data points.

[image]

As can be seen above, I specified `Max Data Points` to `7000`, and yet Influx sent me `10021` rows. If I change `Max Data Points` to `7x24x60=10080`, nothing changes.

When I lower `Max Data Points` to `6680`, then number of rows drops to `5011`.

What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Click on `ⓘ` and you will see more details:
[image]

So it's not a `LIMIT` of InfluxDB query (you can configure that directly in the query), but it affects `$__interval`, which you very likely used in the query and it affects returned records in timeseries (BTW it doesn't make sense to have time grouping, when you are using singlestat panel).

[image]

Comment: Not clear yet. Right now I understand this as follows: I type in `Max Data Points` -> based on this an `$__interval` is determined -> based on this an actual number of data points is determined, which can be limited by setting `LIMIT`. Is this correct?

Comment: @SantaXL please read documentation - keywords: InfluxDB time grouping, InfluxQL LIMIT clause, Grafana `$__interval` macro. Usage of `Grafana query inspector` can be also useful for you.